# html5 background video going full screen as you try to type on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm having a weird issue. On this page http://jota.info/assinatura, if you click on the left menu "voltar", click on the "Login" and type "felipe.seligman" as a user you will notice that you can't type the letter m, and then if you type the letter F again, the video playing behind will go full screen.

1. Do we have default hotkeys for html5 videos?
2. Even the video is not focus, how can while typing on the login field, it triggers the video full screen ?
3. Is there a way to prevent that?

Tested on FF/Chrome/Safari for MAC.

Best

Answer (score 0):

That's more an issue with MediaElement.js you're using in your theme I think. I'm not so familiar with ME.js, but a guess: in file jquery.main.js try adding in

```
function VideoBG(options) {
        this.options = $.extend({
            videoOptions: {
```

following attribute:

```
enableKeyboard: false,
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Hi @Christian Bush, thanks for the tip mate, i tried to set the enableKeyboard: false and didn't wok, although I believe that i'm closer now to figure out to so solve this issue.